# How can I get my plotly graph title to display using Dash?

Tags: plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a couple of plotly graphs that I can display with fig.show(), but when I try and display them using Dash instead, their titles disappear.

With fig.show(): [Graph made with fig.show()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUoAj.png)

With Dash: [Graph made with Dash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQr1e.png)

I don't think the issue with my code has to do with how I've initialized `fig` because the graph displays perfectly if I replace my code under the "Display" section with just `fig.show()`.

Would love to know if anyone has any ideas for how to get my graph titles working with Dash!

```py
import os
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

import numpy as np
import math

# ---------- Initialize X, Y, Z ----------

def f(x, y):
    return 1/2 * (math.pow(x+y,4)+math.pow(x-y,4))

X = np.arange(-10, 11, 1)
Y = X
Z = np.zeros((21,21))

for i in range(21):
    for j in range(21):
        Z[i][j] = f(X[i], Y[j])

# ---------- Generate graphs ----------

layout = {'title': {'text':'DISPLAY ME!'}}

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(x = X, y = Y, z = Z)], layout=layout)

# ---------- Display ----------

app = dash.Dash()
app.title = "Steepest Descent"

server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(
        children=[dcc.Graph(id='my-graph', figure=fig)]
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Your code works fine for me. Please see the versions of dash libraries Im using:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
dash                      1.11.0             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
dash-bootstrap-components 0.9.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
dash-core-components      1.9.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
dash-daq                  0.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
dash-html-components      1.0.3              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
dash-renderer             1.4.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
dash-table                4.6.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
```

Comment: Ah thank you! My dash-core-components was out of date and upgrading it solved the issue.